# How to create meaningful unit test when error message is only a temporary text bubble

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, cypress

I am doing Cypress registration test and "Create account" button is always clickable, no matter how many empty or wrongly filled fields. All that happens when wrong form is submitted is a bubble with error message like on screenshot, that isn't DOM and lasts for a few second (so I can't make assertion like expect(bubble).to.be.visible)[image: error bubble]

I would like to type wrong data and prove that application isn't accepting them. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can actually validate the HTML form validation in cypress. You can look here -  [Can I check that a form's HTML form validation is shown when input is invalid?](https://docs.cypress.io/faq/questions/using-cypress-faq#Can-I-check-that-a-form-s-HTML-form-validation-is-shown-when-an-input-is-invalid)

```js
cy.get('[type="email"]').then(($input) => {
  expect($input[0].validationMessage).to.eq('I expect an email!')
})
```